# How do I stop Sitecore caching my custom data provider?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, dataprovider

I have a custom data provider pulling in data via a webservice.

I have pretty much followed this example here: http://www.techphoria414.com/Blog/Black-Art-of-Sitecore-Data-Providers.aspx

Sitecore seems to be caching my data provider though. For example, I load my application for the first time, and the data get pulled from the provider as I would expect. However, if i collapse the tree and reopen it again, I would expect by provider to be called again, but it is not.

I thought it might be stored in the prefecth cache or in a lucene index, but clearing those didn't cause a call back to my provider again.

How do I tell it to always get data from my data provider?

Comment: Turns out the issue was a bug in my own code. If you want to disable caching on your provider though, you can do  `this.CacheOptions.DisableAll = true;`

Comment: Lee, when you get a moment you should answer your question rather than just leave a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the issue was a bug in my own code. If you want to disable caching on your provider though, you can do:

```
this.CacheOptions.DisableAll = true;
```